vscode scala metals don't see projects that are created as sub-module
I have a project that uses git-submodules. The submodule is a scala project by itself. Here's my project structure:
-- build.sbt
-- module/build.sbt
The module is a git-submodule. Now I try to import the root project in which the module is imported to the root project like this:
lazy val myModule = ProjectRef(file("module"), "module")

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(myModule)

Now the problem is that in VsCode the metals seem to not create the configuration file (.bloop/myModule.json) and it doesn't compile myModule in the root project in which the code depends on classes from myModule. Is there a way to configure it?
versions: vscode-1.90.1 metals-v1.35.0

Does it work if you use sbt as the BSP rather than bloop?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez how to switch it or check? haven't found any vs-code metals settings for it. also the sbt itself works fine (compiles, etc.) and it does work with intellij

There is a metals command called "Switch build server" if you run it you can choose sbt
